# Efficiently expanding a String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a small function to act as .push for a string[][] array.

Here is a simplified version of what I have.

```
String[][] myData = new String[43][12];
    //... fill myData array for a web service that would have returned the 12
```

Now I have to add +1, as we know the array is *immutable, or cannot be changed.
What I want is to essentially pass a function to expand it and was hoping for some help

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myData_temp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> entry = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(ii = 0; ii < 43; ii++){
        entry.put("_"+ii, "Maybe some random text...");
    }
alldata_setup.add(entry);

myData_AddEntry(alldata_setup);

....

public function myData_AddEntry(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> valueToAdd){
    //Create a Copy of myData
    String[][] myData_temp = myData;//Would this work? Is there a better way to duplicate?
    myData = new String[43][myData_temp[0].length + 1]
    //Then move old data into the array
    myData = myData_temp;
    //Then add newest entry
    for(ii = 0; ii < 43; ii++){
        myData[ii][myData[0].length] = valueToAdd.get("_"+ii);
    }
}
```

I know that this might be very rough / crude. However, I am looking to use an array like this myData[][] as this will make my life easier when I go between android Java, PHP, AS3 which the other 2 are already easily using this format and I want to try my best to keep it consistent for my sake.

Ideally I am looking to accomplish 2 things.

1 - Re-initialize my global myData array, while keeping all the old data

2 - Add into myData array the new values in the now open slot.

Many thanks for any help to come. I really must stay with the String[][] approach to help myself instead of delving too far into arrayList, lists, hashmaps, sparseArrays, HashMap>.. I kind of inherited a hot mess and need to start cleaning things up for anything to make sense. And the best way I know of to do that is to go back to what is known and be able to draw parallels between all the other projects and apply it to this so that anyone working on all 3 will not have too many issues when changing between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
    ... 

    String[][] newData = new String[43][];
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        String[] row = data[i];
        newData[i] = Arrays.copyOf(row, row.length + 1);
    }

    // fill in new data column in newData
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it just make a second String[][] copy the data into it then save the new array into your variable.